# How to match ID to a lookup table in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset that has has a lot of products purchased that looks something like this.

[image]

Is there a way of joining the product to a lookup table (looks like this[image]

When I try and join it gives me an error. is there something I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pivot the first dataset so that all the products are in a single column and then you can join to the second dataset